# Does minus value in ‘from’ field make cluster status red?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I have a problem with my cluster and trying to figure it out why. I found this exception in logs. I know minus value in this field is wrong but does it make cluster status red?

Elastic version: 1.7.3

> org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [{$myindex}][0]:
>   from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [from is set to [-2] and is expected
>   to be higher or equal to 0]

Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't, you must have other issues, but this one certainly isn't the cause. Look further in your logs, what do you see around the line that said `Cluster health status changed from [GREEN] to [RED]`

Comment: Well, I couldnt find anything like this in my logs. Should I enable debug or info logs?

Comment: Can you provide the logs from when you cluster is starting?